# MySQL XML Export with NULL in data does not re-import due to a bug

Tags: mysql, xml, import, null, export

Using the MySQL CLI command to export a row from a table, eg:-

```
mysql -h mysql --user=root --password=root --database dms_home --xml -e "SELECT * FROM users WHERE account=4149;" >/var/www/scripts/output/1187515/1187515_users.sql
```

This outputs the file:-

```
<resultset statement="SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE accnum=1187515" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <row>
    <field name="id">4149</field>
    <field name="accnum">1187515</field>
    <field name="applicationdate">0000-00-00</field>
    <field name="introducer"></field>
    <field name="jointacc">0</field>
    <field name="consultancy">0</field>
    <field name="storage">0</field>
    <field name="digitalonly">0</field>
    <field name="membership" xsi:nil="true" />
    <field name="promocode"></field>
    <field name="holdername" xsi:nil="true" />
    <field name="testaccount">0</field>
  </row>
</resultset>
```

Now as you can see there are 2 nulls within XML row "membership" and "holdername", if I then go to another MySQL server/database and re-import this file, wiht the show warnings switch I get this back:-

```
mysql -h mysql -u root -p dms_licence --show-warnings -e "load xml local infile '/var/www/scripts/output/1187515/1187515_account.sql' into table dms_licence.accounts";


Warning (Code 1263): Column set to default value; NULL supplied to NOT NULL column 'id' at row 1
Warning (Code 1263): Column set to default value; NULL supplied to NOT NULL column 'accnum' at row 1
Warning (Code 1263): Column set to default value; NULL supplied to NOT NULL column 'applicationdate' at row 1
Warning (Code 1263): Column set to default value; NULL supplied to NOT NULL column 'introducer' at row 1
Warning (Code 1263): Column set to default value; NULL supplied to NOT NULL column 'jointacc' at row 1
Warning (Code 1263): Column set to default value; NULL supplied to NOT NULL column 'consultancy' at row 1
Warning (Code 1263): Column set to default value; NULL supplied to NOT NULL column 'storage' at row 1
Warning (Code 1263): Column set to default value; NULL supplied to NOT NULL column 'digitalonly' at row 1
Warning (Code 1263): Column set to default value; NULL supplied to NOT NULL column 'promocode' at row 1
Warning (Code 1263): Column set to default value; NULL supplied to NOT NULL column 'testaccount' at row 1
```

The table schemas are identical and the inserting data does not cause any issues with primary or unique keys. So why does it only insert a blank record ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with MySQL 5.5x I haven't tested with MySQL 5.6x but the issue seems to be on reimport that the field rows defined in the XML as null values (denoted in the XML as xsi:nil="true" /> ) causes this issue.

It appears that the MySQL CLI import process for reading XML is at fault and can't handle the short hand way of closing out the field node.

So this fails:-

but this works:-

A quick work around for this is to still PIPE out the file but then change out the :-

```
xsi:nil="true" />
```

with

```
xsi:nil="true"></field>
```

The reason I believe this is safe is due to xsi:nil never equalling false because if there is a value then it would just lay beween the   tags.

So how do you change this out...... well I am going to find out now and come back and update.... more soon.

Hope this initial pointer helps others as it was driving me mad into the wee hours trying to work out what was going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick search and replace on files using PHP which is what I am using for the overall project, see here -> [find and replace values in a flat-file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944080/find-and-replace-values-in-a-flat-file-using-php)

But it would be cool if I could do it at a OS level on Linux (CentOS) so PHP doesn't have to handle massive files, I need to search for :-

```
" xsi:nil=\"true\" />"
```

and change it to:-

```
" xsi:nil=\"true\"></field>"
```

Good luck on finding that :)